# Why does my UILabel shows up delayed about 10 seconds after everything else?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uilabel

I have a problem. In my xCode project, I added a label on the main storyboard but when I actually compile and run the app, the `UILabel` shows up around 10 seconds after everything else. Anybody knows what could be the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail? Is your UILabel already visible since the beginning or are you making it visible inside an async thread?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The UILabel is visible since the beginning and I actually don't do anything with it, it's not even connected as a variable to the View controller. Please let me know if you have any other questions and thanks for the interest.

Comment: Do you have any other views in your storyboard and do they appear instantly?

Comment: I do. Yes, all the other views appear instantly and all the labels appear delayed.

Comment: please remove the slow animations effect of simulator

Comment: I'm actually not using the simulator. I'm building the app on my iPhone

Comment: Is it made in a storyboard or via code? If in code when is it called and what is being set for its properties.

Comment: It's made in a storyboard

Comment: I think your view controller may have problem of constraint. I think your constraint are breaking and label are trying to adjust it according to provided constraint.

Comment: For one of the labels changing the constraint worked, for another one it didn't. It's pretty weird, I'm not completely sure why is it doing that. There were some warnings for the constraints earlier but now there's none anymore and one of the labels still shows up after like 20 seconds now.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably populating the label text from a background thread; any updates to UI elements may have mysterious delays if you do not adjust them on the main thread.  Try wrapping the code that sets the label text in a perform_async() call on the main queue...

Comment: The kind of weird thing is that I actually don't set the value of the UILabel on my view controller, I just set it from on my storyboard and the stay constant. I don't update them. That's why I really don't get what could be the problem. Thanks for the answer though. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: That's what I thought first too. But he says that the uilabel is not connected to the controller as an outlet. So I don't think he is accessing it via any background threads.